# The BCH series in terms of Lyndon words

Tags: free-lie-algebras

Recently I did some explicit computations that involved the BCH series, $\log(e^x e^y)$. Here $x$ and $y$ are non-commuting variables, and the BCH series lives in the graded completion $FL(x,y)$ of the free Lie algebra generated by $x$ and $y$.

Mostly by chance I found that when BCH is written in the Lyndon basis of $FL(x,y)$, the number of Lyndon words that occur in its degree $n$ piece is {2, 1, 2, 1, 6, 5, 18, 17, 55, 55, 186, 185, 630, 629, 2181, 2181, 7710, 7709, 27594, 27593, 99857, 99857}, for $n$ running from 1 to 22.

There is an obvious pattern in this sequence - it seems that the odd-numbered terms are almost equal to the even-numbered terms that follow them, with a decline of one in 2/3 of the times, and with precise equality in the remaining 1/3 of the times. I have no idea why this is so. Perhaps you do?

Why care? The truth is that I'm curious but I don't care much; I just stumbled upon this by chance. Yet Lyndon words are a very effective tool for computations in free Lie algebras, and the BCH formula appears in many of these computations. The fact that there is some unexpected symmetry in the Lyndon word description of BCH suggests that BCH contains less information than one might think, possibly leading to some computational advantage. Though in (my) reality, the computational bottlenecks are anyway elsewhere.

Some further details and observations are at http://drorbn.net/AcademicPensieve/2012-12/nb/BCH-Lyndon_Question.pdf.

Comment: For comparison, I wonder if you could remind us the total number of Lyndon words in each of these spaces?  I assume it's growing much faster than the sequence you computed, but I could imagine that BCH essentially saturates some natural subspace of of FL(x,y), say the subspace with some obvious symmetry, and that the pattern is exactly the pattern of dimensions of those spaces.

Comment: Ah, I see that you answer (at least) some of my question in the linked pdf, which I have only just started to read.

Comment: Is it really periodic or something more like a sturmian sequence? Namely, if one writes "A" whenever the even and odd guys coincide, and then "B" whenever they don't, then one gets a (semi-)infinite word in two letters "A" and "B". Is this sequence ultimately periodic or sturmian (the later meaning that it is of minimal complexity among non-periodic words)?

Comment: For what it's worth, the sequence (2, 1, 2, 1, 6, ...) doesn't seem to be in the On-line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences.

Comment: It looks to me (from the data in the linked pdf) like there are two different perhaps not-so-related things that are happening: at n odd, BCH gets all possible Lyndon words except one of them when n=6k+3 (k>0), in which case it misses x^{4k+1}yx^{2k}y, and at n=2k, the Lyndon words that appear in BCH are exactly those obtainable from the Lyndon words of length 2k-1 by prepending x, except that x^{2k-1}y does not appear.  I have no explanations, though. 

Comment: @Hugh: You are right, and the pattern you note continues at least to degree 20. I've added a note on that to the PDF file. (Pages 5-6 in present version, may move later).

Comment: Okay, I can establish what is probably the least interesting of my observations.  It's straightforward to check that the terms in BCH of the form yx^n are exactly yx/(e^x-1).  Now x/(e^x-1) is a familiar power series, and its only odd-degree term is -x/2 (subtract this off and what is left is an even function).  This shows that the Lyndon word <x^{n-1}y> doesn't appear for even n at least 4.  (It also points out that my statement wasn't quite correct for n=2: <xy> does appear.)

Comment: Let me mention that the Lyndon words of length n obtained by prepending an x, form a basis of the subspace of FL_n of the form [x,FL_{n-1}].  This seems as if it could be helpful for showing that only terms of this form appear in the n-even case.  

Comment: I tool a liberty to add this sequence to the OEIS as http://oeis.org/A220587

Comment: The two sequences seem to coincide exactly when the index is a prime number (or $1$). Is this expected ? Could it be checked for $n=23$ ?

Comment: @F.C.- I don't understand your comment. Precisely which two sequences? I haven't noticed any prime numbers in the business. Anyway, 23 is certainly within reach, as computers mightier than my laptop certainly exist. But it will be a few hours of work to find one and re-run the programs, and I'm not sure if/when this will happen.

Comment: For n <= 22, the number of all Lyndon words is equal to the number of Lyndon words in BCH exactly if n is prime. Namely the exceptions 9, 15, 21 are the ood numbers which are not prime. I observed something similar in my own research in a different context (full support in prime degrees).

Comment: Hmm., I was interpreting this as "a period of 6". I guess more evidence is needed, perhaps up to 25. I don't think my mathematica program will do that.

Comment: The article http://www.ehu.es/ccwmuura/research/bch.pdf by Casas and Murua seems to consider similar questions, in particular section IV.C

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This pattern of vanishing coefficients in the expansion of the Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula in the basis of Lyndon words is explained in section IV.C of the article [An efficient algorithm for computing the Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff series
and some of its applications](http://www.ehu.es/ccwmuura/research/bch.pdf) of Fernando Casas and Ander Murua.